# Recommendation for skinning library for Windows forms

Tags: winforms, themes, skinning

I'm looking for a skinning library for Windows Forms.

I see this question asked a few times on StackOverflow, but always people looking for free/open source solutions.  I don't mind paying for a skinning library.  Googling around I see DevExpress's controls support some kind of skinning, and there's also skincrafter.com (though I'm unclear if that supports Windows Forms).  Anyone familiar with either of these products or can recommend something better?

I'd like "full" skinning support, but I might be happy with something simple like Firefox Personas/Chrome Themes.

I'm used to using the DotNetBar controls but they don't seem to support skinning, other than basic color themes.

Answer (score 3):

I use DevExpress WinForms and I'm very happy with them.

However, developing custom controls that look good in all of their included skins can be quite challenging.